# Как узнать символ в консоли под курсором?

Tags: c#, консоль

Например в консоли есть символ "#" в координатах (0,0)
как узнать что там символ "#" ,а не "?"

Comment: Напрямую врядли, импортировать [readconsoleoutputcharacter](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleoutputcharacter)

Comment: А как вы, простите, определяете, что у вас в шкафу на второй полке справа стоит бутылка, а не тарелка? Отрываете шкаф и смотрите, так? Ну, так прочитайте символ с нужной координатой и посмотрите какой он, не?

Comment: @Bulson для етого нужно знать функцию смотрения на предмет :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Штатные средства класса `Console` не позволяют читать напрямую из выходного буфера, хотя WinAPI, поверх которого работают методы `Console`, такое позволяет. Следовательно придется импортировать нужные функции руками. Выглядеть будет как-то так:

```
class Program
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    struct COORD
    {
        public short X;
        public short Y;
    }

    // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/ReadConsoleOutputCharacter.html
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(
        IntPtr hConsoleOutput,
        [Out] char[] lpCharacter,
        int nLength,
        COORD dwReadCoord,
        out int lpNumberOfCharsRead
        );

    // http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetStdHandle.html
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(
        int nStdHandle
        );

    static void Main()
    {
        //выводим символ
        Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 10);
        char outChar = 'K';
        Console.Write(outChar);
        //читаем символ
        char[] readBuffer = new char[1];
        int readCount;
        ReadConsoleOutputCharacter(GetStdHandle(-11), readBuffer, 1, new COORD() { X = 10, Y = 10 }, out readCount);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine($"{readBuffer[0] == outChar}");
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
}
```

Демка построена на основе примеров кода с [pinvoke.net](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.ConsoleFunctions) с небольшими модификациями.